# Serving a website project AND a webservice project off same IIS and same port (80)?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis

**Background:**

I have a Visual Studio solution consisting of a website + REST web-service that I'd like to split into a web services project and a web site project.

Currently, the web service is kicked off during application startup via `App_Code\global.asax.cs`, with the following code:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("api/", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(myWebInterfaceSvc)));
    }
    // more code here
}
```

I imagine I'll need to split it up starting from the above ...

**Concern:**

Now, my concern is that without the common HTTP handler and extra route above i.e. once I have them as two separate projects, they will be two separate IIS sites/applications so they will run on two different ports. I'd still like BOTH to respond to port 80 as

http(s)://www.site.com -> web site project

http(s)://www.site.com/api -> web service

Assuming I'm successful in separating the website and the web service, how would I setup IIS for the above?

Comment: why don't you create a sub-virtual-directory on IIS and host the webservice in that sub-directory ?

Comment: err ... not sure! Probably because I'm like a zombie today and am dreaming up non-existent issues :) ? I'll rethink this tomorrow...

Comment: Could you be more helpful? you mean you tried that solution or u mean it's so obvious so i even don't want to think about it ?

Comment: I meant you comment was pretty helpful and that I don't know why I didn't think about it (lack of sleep?). I'll try this out but also remembered this morning that I authenticate users on the site AND service - so when I break it down, I'll need some kind of SSO too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up setting the main website as the root / primary site in IIS and then added the service as a virtual sub directory within that.

Comment: FYI, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/

Comment: @DeepSpace101 did you automate this? I found New-WebVirtualDirectory is the powershell command to create the directory. But I actually have two separetate webservices under /api. How to I make routing work?